# Wordpress categories by the current author

Tags: wordpress, categories, author

Is there a way to get this...

```
wp_list_categories('sort_order=asc&style=list&hide_empty=0&children=false&hierarchical=false&exclude=1&title_li=0&show_count=1&show_option_none=');
```

...to only show the categories for the currently logged in author? I've tried a few things none of which work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, WordPress keeps authoring track only for posts. Not terms, e.g. tags, categor…